# Stock data mining for a company

Tags: python

new to python and have a problem to solve that I've hit a roadblock.
Looking to calculate the monthly and yearly average price for Google and tell us the best and worst six months and the best and worst six years for Google from 2004 to Oct 2019
The average price is defined as ((v1*c1)+(v2*c2)+(v3*c3)+(v4*c4)...+(vn*cn)) / (v1+v2+v3+v4...+vn) where vi is the volume for day i and ci is the adjusted close price for day i.

I've been able to import the data from the web but now I'm trying to at least get one year into a tuple and then work out from that but can't figure out how to convert the data I have into a tuple.
I try function = tuple but get errors. I know how to make a tuple but not how to make one from the data I have or if I'm missing a step to get the data into one or if I'm going off track with this approach

Here is my code so far if anyone could point me in the right direction it would be appreciated

```
# url = "http://193.1.33.31:88/pa1/GOOGL.csv"


import csv

import begin
from read_from_file_or_net import get_stuff_from_net as gn

def main(csv_file: 'URL of CSV file'):
# def main(csv_file):

    try:
        print(f"{csv_file}")
        my_file = gn(csv_file)
        # with open(f".cache/{my_file}", "w") as output:
        #     output.write(my_file)

        my_file = my_file.split("\n")

        for row in my_file:
            row = row.strip().split(",")
            for cell in row:
                if cell.isalpha():
                    print(f"{cell}"+"", end="")
                elif "-" in cell:
                    print(f"{cell}", end="")
                elif "." in cell:
                    print(f"{float(cell):>10.2f}", end="")
                elif cell.isnumeric():
                    print(f"{int(cell):>15d}", end="")
                elif not cell.isspace():
                    print(f"{cell}", end="  ")
                #elif cell.istitle():
                   # print(f"{cell}", end="")
                #else:
                    #print("?", end="")
            print()

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"{e}")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main("http://193.1.33.31:88/pa1/GOOGL.csv")
```

Comment: maybe better use pandas - `df = pandas.read_csv('http://193.1.33.31:88/pa1/GOOGL.csv')` - and you get all as `DataFrame` (table/array) with many powerful functions.

Comment: to conver the data in the csv to a tuple I tried ```main("http://193.1.33.31:88/pa1/GOOGL.csv") = tup_year_avg2019```

Comment: you try to assign some value `tup_year_avg2019` to result from function `main()` - it is not correct in any language. maybe you means `tup_year_avg2019 = main()` but it would need to put data on list, not print them, and use `return` send them back.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @furas I have no experience using pandas apart from reading up on it but from what I've seen it may make my life easier but I thought doing it this way might be a better learning experience, but I could be totally wrong

Comment: you can try to do it on your own if you want to learn Python basis. And later you can learn how to do it with `pandas` because `pandas` is very powerful - so it is good to know it - and it can be very complex - so it need also time to learn it.

Comment: to assign value you need `=`, not `==`. But your current `main()` doesn't return any value - `print()` sends on screen but it doesn't return to variable.

Comment: thanks, I spotted the typo with == and used ``` tup_year_avg2019 = main("http://193.1.33.31:88/pa1/GOOGL.csv") ```

Comment: in answer I added example without `pandas` - it uses only `for`-loops

Comment: @furas thanks so much for your help on this, I'm just going to go have a look at your answers to try to get my head around it

Answer (score 1):

You should use `pandas` for this. It has many powerful functions which doesn't need `for`-loop.

You can read `csv` directly from web page

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('http://193.1.33.31:88/pa1/GOOGL.csv')

print(df.columns)
print(df.head())
```

You can select one year - ie. 2018

```
year2018 = df[ (df['Date'] >= '2018-01-01') & (df['Date'] < '2019-01-01') ]
```

And calculate your value

```
result = (year2018['Volume'] * year2018['Adj Close']).sum() / year2018['Volume'].sum()

print(result)
```

---

**EDIT:** Silimar for other years

```
for year in range(2004, 2019):
    year = str(year)
    data = df[ df['Date'].str.startswith(year) ]
    result = (data['Volume'] * data['Adj Close']).sum() / data['Volume'].sum()

    print(year, result)
```

Result:

```
2004 80.44437157567273
2005 137.4076040074354
2006 203.03824165240846
2007 273.04059204266287
2008 227.86912213843564
2009 206.71221450434697
2010 268.65533171697064
2011 283.70689930771306
2012 322.70466840310667
2013 437.32701278816154
2014 567.9540540371448
2015 623.3613056057101
2016 757.9295821975054
2017 940.267270383813
2018 1115.287148437416
```

---

**EDIT:** If you keep results on list as tuples `(result, year)` then you can sort them to get the best and the worst years

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('http://193.1.33.31:88/pa1/GOOGL.csv')
#df['Date'] = pandas.to_datetime(df['Date'])

#print(df.columns)

year2018 = df[ (df['Date'] >= '2018-01-01') & (df['Date'] < '2019-01-01') ]

result = (year2018['Volume'] * year2018['Adj Close']).sum() / year2018['Volume'].sum()

#print(result)

all_results = []
for year in range(2004, 2019):
    year = str(year)
    data = df[ df['Date'].str.startswith(year) ]
    result = (data['Volume'] * data['Adj Close']).sum() / data['Volume'].sum()

    all_results.append( (result, year) )
    #print(year, result)

print('--- sorted by result ---')

sorted_results = sorted(all_results)

for result, year in sorted_results:
    print(year, result)
```

Result:

```
--- sorted by result ---
2004 80.44437157567273
2005 137.4076040074354
2006 203.03824165240846
2009 206.71221450434697
2008 227.86912213843564
2010 268.65533171697064
2007 273.04059204266287
2011 283.70689930771306
2012 322.70466840310667
2013 437.32701278816154
2014 567.9540540371448
2015 623.3613056057101
2016 757.9295821975054
2017 940.267270383813
2018 1115.287148437416
```

Using slice `sorted_results[:6]` you can get six the worst years, using `sorted_results[-6:]` you can get six the best years. You can also use `reversed()` if you want in different order.

---

**EDIT:** Almost all the same without `pandas`

```
import requests
import csv

def main(url):
    r = requests.get(url)

    lines = r.text.split('\n')

    headers = lines[0].split(',')

    data = []

    for line in lines[1:]:
        line = line.strip()
        if line: # skip empty lines
            row = line.strip().split(',')

            # convert string to float/int
            row[1] = float(row[1])
            row[2] = float(row[2])
            row[3] = float(row[3])
            row[4] = float(row[4])
            row[5] = float(row[5])
            row[6] = int(row[6])

            data.append(row)

    return headers, data


if __name__ == "__main__":    
    headers, data = main('http://193.1.33.31:88/pa1/GOOGL.csv')

    print(headers)

    print('--- data ---')
    print(data[0])
    print(data[-1])

    # get only year 2018

    year2018 = []
    for row in data:
        if '2018-01-01' <= row[0] < '2019-01-01':
           year2018.append(row)

    print('--- year 2018 ---')
    print(year2018[0])
    print(year2018[-1])

    # your calculation

    a = 0
    b = 0
    for row in year2018:
        a += row[5] * row[6]
        b += row[6]

    result = a/b

    print(result)
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how would this be done with a rolling window efficiently? If he's asking for the best six months, could that not be calculated from the start of every single month for a period of six months?

Comment: @poorpractice at start I made it only for one year and later I resize it to all years. And later I added sorting and slicing to get six years only. So I wasn't thinking how to do it at once in more efficiently way. I was only thinking about `groupby` but finally I skip it as too much new things at once for beginner :) If you have idea how to do it more efficiently then add it as another answer - it can be useful for OP and other users.